# Howto make one Power BI pie chart widget from two columns data / or merge two pies in one

Tags: user-interface, powerbi, pie-chart

I have a table with two columns (more in real life)

```
| firmware_check_result    | software_check_result |
| -------------------------|-----------------------|
| firmware checksum error  | software outated      |
| firmware outated         | software slow         |
|                          | software bug          |
```

Results can be any text from a predefined list of reasons.
But results are different in both columns. And a row can have one or no firmware check result and one or no software check result.

I need to build one unique pie chart with all the data from both columns.
Is it possible ? and how to to it ?

I tried to add both columns like this:

- Drop a Pie chart on canvas
- in Properties:

  - in Legend: I added both columns
  - in Values: I added both columns

Result is strange as I have one pie chart
but legend is only the legend of the 1st column, not the second.

It there a way to do this ?

[image]
This shows a result with 3 results possibilities but legend has only two and colors are the same for 2 out of 3 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. For simplicity I will use only your example columns in my answer:

1. Create a new query using the same data as before

   - Keep only the `firmware_check_result` and `software_check_result` columns, as well as an index or unique identifier (UID) column of some kind (and any other information you think may be useful later)

     - I will refer to the UID column as `[UID]`
2. Select and [unpivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) your `firmware_check_result` and `software_check_result` columns in the new query

   - Close and apply the changes
3. Create a new [relationship](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-dfa453a7-0b6d-4c34-a128-fdebc7e686af) between your original table and your new unpivoted table based on `[UID]`
4. Create a new pie chart

   - For your values, use `Count of [UID]`
   - In the legend, from your new unpivoted query, place `Attribute` first, then `Value` underneath

     - You can switch between the two levels using `Drill Up` and `Expand all down one level in hierarchy` or `Go to next level in hierarchy`

Comment: This seems to work fine. Is it valid to "Add an index column with Power Query" to replace the UID ? as I do not have an easy unique id otherwise ?

Comment: Absolutely! If you don't have a good column to use this would do the trick.